# Почему не заменяется текст через регулярное выражение?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, файлы, input

У меня почему-то **не заменяется первые слова до первого знака (;)** через регулярку. Почему так происходит?

Ниже прилагаю свой код + файл в котором есть инормация + вывод который мне необходим

Код Util:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Util {
    private static final String ENCODING = "Cp1251";

    public static String readFile(String path) {
        String res = null;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            res = new String(bytes, ENCODING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(readFile("part1.txt"));
    }
}
```

Мой код (в комментариях входная и выходная информация):

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public static String convert2(String input) throws FileNotFoundException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Util.readFile(input));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();

            stringBuilder.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        String ConvertTwo_First = stringBuilder.toString().replaceFirst("Login;Name;Email", "");
        String regexTwo = "^\\w+\\W";

        Pattern patternTwo = Pattern.compile(regexTwo, Pattern.MULTILINE + Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        Matcher matcherTwo = patternTwo.matcher(ConvertTwo_First);

        String strTwo = "";

        while (matcherTwo.find()) {
            strTwo = ConvertTwo_First.replaceAll(regexTwo, "asd") + matcherTwo.start();
        }
        return strTwo;
    }

    /* -----------INPUT DATA------------
    Login;Name;Email
    ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com
    петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
    obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com
    bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com
    */

    /* -----------OUTPUT DATA------------
    Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com
    Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
    Barack Obama;obama@google.com
    Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(convert2(FILENAME));
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой конечный результат вам нужен? Возможно это легче сделать через String[] info = input.split(";");, а потом просто работать с массивом?

Comment: @JackFromBB Мне нужен такой конечный результат, он находится в комментариях кода

    Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com
    Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
    Barack Obama;obama@google.com
    Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com

В задании нельзя использовать массивы, только через регулярные выражения

Comment: Понял.  Последний вопрос, вам нужен ответ на поставленный вопрос, или подойдёт метод получающий нужный ответ?

Comment: @JackFromBB нужен метод именно

Comment: @БогданКостевич вы не из одного вуза с [туц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074184/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) ?

Comment: @dmtr да, с одного) только у меня на выходе нужно получить чуть другой результат

Answer (score 0):

На конкретный вопрос по вашему коду ответить не могу. Сложновато мне читать чужой код, сори, но можете попробовать вот этот метод:

```
String input = "Login;Name;Email" +
        "\nivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com" +
        "\nпетров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com" +
        "\nobama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com" +
        "\nbush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com";

private String toAnswer(String input){
    input = input.replace("Login;Name;Email","");
    String patternString = "(.*);(.*);(.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while (matcher.find()){
        String match = matcher.group();
        String answer = match.substring(match.indexOf(";")+1)+"\n";
        Log.i("Строка", answer);
        builder.append(answer);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```